# Extra vertical space in shaded theorem if ended with displaymath or itemize

Tags: spacing, environments, theorems, framed

I have created custom shaded theorems but when ended with displaymath or itemize/enumerate environment, there is extra vertical space.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newtheoremstyle{thm}
    {0pt} % space above
    {0pt} % space below
    {\rmfamily} % body font
    {} % indent amount
    {\rmfamily} % theorem head font
    {.} % punctuation after theorem head
    {0.5em} % space after theorem head
    {} % theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{thm}
\newtheorem{boilerexample}[section]{Example}
\newenvironment{example}
   {\colorlet{shadecolor}{teal!15}\begin{shaded}\begin{boilerexample}}
   {\end{boilerexample}\end{shaded}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{example}
        This is an example.
    \end{example}

    \begin{example}
        This is an example that ends with displaymath.
        \[ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \]
    \end{example}

    \begin{example}
        This is an example that ends with an itemize environment.
        \begin{itemize}
            \item This is an item.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{example}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:
[image]

The extra vertical space in the second and third environments is undesirable. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you want `\newtheorem{boilerexample}[section]{Example}`? Do you maybe want `\newtheorem{boilerexample}{Example}[section]` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do: the last vertical skip is removed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newtheoremstyle{thm}
    {0pt} % space above
    {0pt} % space below
    {\rmfamily} % body font
    {} % indent amount
    {\rmfamily} % theorem head font
    {.} % punctuation after theorem head
    {0.5em} % space after theorem head
    {} % theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{thm}
\newtheorem{boilerexample}[section]{Example}
\newenvironment{example}
   {\colorlet{shadecolor}{teal!15}\begin{shaded}\begin{boilerexample}}
   {%
    \end{boilerexample}%
    \par\removelastskip
    \end{shaded}
   }

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{example}
        This is an example.
    \end{example}

    \begin{example}
        This is an example that ends with displaymath.
        \[ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \]
    \end{example}

    \begin{example}
        This is an example that ends with an itemize environment.
        \begin{itemize}
            \item This is an item.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]